# Convert this html to haml

Tags: haml

I need to convert this to haml

```
   <link href="/skin/jplayer.blue.monday.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://www.htmltohaml.com/ for this sort of translation in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
%link{:href => "/skin/jplayer.blue.monday.css", :rel => "stylesheet" :type => "text/css"}
```

Link isn't specifically mentioned in the [HAML reference](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html), but with HAML you can assume that a tag will take the form:

```
%tagname{:attr1 => "val1", :attr2 => "val2", ...}
```

Link is among [the tags that are automatically closed by default](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#selfclosing_tags_), as long as they have no content.